# Is it bad to declare global app variable in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've seen a lot of examples online showing the following basic AngularJS code:

```
var app = angular.module("ExampleApp", []);  // setter, creates a new module

app.controller(...
```

and in other files that are under the same Angular module:

```
var app = angular.module("ExampleApp");  // getter, retrieves the existing module

app.service(...
```

This reads into memory a global "app" variable, which is accessible across other files. The second file works if I get rid of the "getter" and just start right off with `app.service(...`.

I assume this is a bad practice to not use the getter and just use the global variable in the first place, but I'm wondering if it's a bad practice to declare the global variable *at all*. My first thoughts are to wrap every file in an IIFE to locally scope the variables, or to get rid of the `var app` part and just chain the `.controller`, `.service`, etc. right onto the `angular.module()`.

Thanks in advance for your professional advice.

Comment: Would `app.myGlobal = 'hello world'` not work?

Comment: It's the same problem really as any other sort of global variable. Yes, it can certainly have an impact. In production you would probably indeed wrap it in an IIFE, probably your actual production Javascript build system would do that while compiling/packing your Javascript.

Comment: How do you know  `var app` is a global variable? Are you sure it's not inside a (commonjs/ES6) module?

Comment: I created a quick sample application, the first file using `var app = angular.module("Example", [])` and in the second file I removed the `var app = angular.module("Example")` completely. Still worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As global variables are mutable everywhere, it's safer and more maintainable to not using global variables. I generally create my modules in a first place js file:

```
angular.module("ExampleApp", []);
```

and get in everyfile without assigning to a variable:

```
angular.module("ExampleApp")
    .service("MyService", function () {});
```

or

```
angular.module("ExampleApp")
    .component("MyComponent", {});
```

If I need some variables I use functions:

```
(function () {
    var myController = function () {};

    myController.$inject = ["$scope"];

    angular.module("ExampleApp")
        .controller(myController);
})();
```

Also using bundlers like [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) is a good option. They automatically create scopes per js files. So you don't need to use immediately invoked functions to hide variables from global scope. For example:

```
var myController = require('./MyController.js');
var myApp = require('./ExampleApp.js');

myApp.controller(myController);
```

In here, with webpack, `myController` and `myApp` variables are not global variables. Simple and clean...

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you use it sometimes we will need it globally but sometimes not but it is preferred to avoid any global variables that's why while writing angular modules we will use self invoking function to avoid access to global values.
In other words if you don't have much complexity you can use global variables but when you have a complex problem avoid using them because you might be using several frameworks and it is possible that your variables can conflict with those in framework and can easily cause problem that will not even understand why it has occurred.